# Can I use a data-toggle dropdown on a li? In Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, toggle, dropdown

I'm making a `dropdown menu` in `bootstrap`.
Now I use in the `li` a `a` element where is described to toggle the dropdown menu.

But I actually want to put what is in the `a` element in to the `li`...
Because the whole `li` has to be clickable.

Hope you guys have I tip for me. ;)

```
<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Applicatie Ontwikkeling
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="list-group-item">HTML</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">CSS</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">jQuery</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Netwerk Beheer</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Server Beheer</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for doing that?

Comment: The hole li have to be clickable @Sahil

Answer (score 0):

please apply 'dropdown' class to the li where you wants to add dropdown like this.

```
<ul class="list-group">
<li class="list-group-item dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Applicatie Ontwikkeling
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="list-group-item">HTML</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">CSS</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">jQuery</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Netwerk Beheer</li>
<li class="list-group-item">Server Beheer</li>
```

Comment: Nope sorry, it does exactly the same as before :(

Answer (score 0):

You can just make the `a` tag take full width and then the entire li becomes clickable.

```css
.dropdown-toggle{
 display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
            Applicatie Ontwikkeling
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="list-group-item">HTML</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">CSS</li>
            <li class="list-group-item">jQuery</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Netwerk Beheer</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Server Beheer</li>
</ul>
```